# Antd form doesn't seem to process line breaks?

Tags: reactjs, forms, antd

Curious if someone has come across this issue - I'm using a form to submit what are essentially comments on a blog, but I switched from a basic React form to an antd form. All is well, but the antd form doesn't seem to process line breaks in the text on input. How do I preserve the line break info in text input that I had with the old form?

Here's code for the old react form:

```
class Submit extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        value: "(Tell a story...)",
      };
  
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
  
    handleChange(event) {
      this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
    }
  
    handleSubmit(event) {
      alert("Your story reads: " + this.state.value);
      event.preventDefault();
      let itemLore = this.state.value;
      console.log("state value test:" + itemLore);
      submitLore(itemLore);
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <textarea value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit ItemLore" />
        </form>
      );
    }
  }
```

The above code handles line breaks correctly, but in using the antd form (for formatting reasons) I'm noticing that line breaks aren't included at all.

Because I'm just importing an antd form, the code below doesn't show of what's under the hood. Any suggestions of what changes I should be making to the antd form to get my line breaks back?

```
<Form.Item name="itemLore">
    <Input.TextArea placeholder="(Tell a story...)"></Input.TextArea>
</Form.Item>
```

Comment: you might need to show what's under the hood.
without `submitLore` or an idea of how you're outputting `state.value` it's hard to know what's happening.
[here's a repo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ksca1k) you can use that is working the way you'd expect

Comment: I made an edit to the original post to see if that clarifies things. My state.value code is working properly BUT the antd form doesn't process line breaks. Do these edits clarify the question?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hmm... I just came across evidence that maybe the problem is stranger than I thought. I'll do more digging and come back to post more details.